# How to show list of string in TextView on Android

Tags: android, arrays, list, textview

I want show list of strings in `TextView` and I get this list from server.
**List from json :**

```
"stars": [
                    {
                        "name": "Elyes Gabel"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Katharine McPhee"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Robert Patrick"
                    }
                ]
```

I want show this names such as this sample :

> Stars = Elyes Gabel, Katharine McPhee, Robert Patrick

I should **setText** from this `TextView` in Adapter.

With below code I can show name :

```
model.get(position).getStars().get(0).getName();
```

But just show me **Elyes Gabel** !!!

I want show me such as this :

> Stars = Elyes Gabel, Katharine McPhee, Robert Patrick

How can I it? Please help me

Comment: use listview and show them as a list. or if you have a single textview loop through your list of values and append it to textview

Comment: @Raghunandan, can you send to me full code? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all "Star" elements and build the string yourself. You should have something like this:

```
String concatenatedStarNames = "";
List<Star> stars = model.get(position).getStars(); // I assume the return value is a list of type "Star"!
for (int i = 0; i < stars.size(); i++) {
  concatenatedStarNames += stars.get(i).getName();
  if (i < stars.size() - 1) concatenatedStarNames += ", ";
}
```

And then you set the text of the text view to `concatenatedStarNames`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct answer you might be after,
Lets just say you have the above JSON and you have converted that in a String array.

So array will look something like below:

```
String stars[] = {Elyes Gabel, Katharine McPhee, Robert Patrick}

TextView textView = // initialise the textview here or however you do.

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String star: stars) {
    builder.append(star);
    builder.append(", ");
}

textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

You will get the desired output...

Answer (score 0):

You can build it yourself with a `StringBuilder`, something like:

```
final Collection<Star> stars = models.get(position).getStars();
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for (Star star : stars) {
    final String name = star.getName();
    if(first) {
        first = false;
        builder.append(name);
    } else {
        builder.append(", ").append(name);
    }
}
final String allStarNames = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do - (with your same logic of accessing stars)

```
String strNames;

for (int i=0; i<starsCount; i++){   //starsCount = No of stars in your JSON
    strNames += model.get(position).getStars().get(i).getName();
    if( i != starsCount-1)
        strNames += ", ";
}

textViewVariable.setText(strNames);
```